# Jest configuration setupFilesAfterEnv option was not found

Tags: path, jestjs

I'm trying to make Jest work again on a project developped 1 year ago and not maintained.

I have an error with path of `setupFilesAfterEnv`or `transform`.

- the error i get when i run "yarn test"

  ```
  $ jest __testsv2__ --config=./jest.config.js
  ● Validation Error:

  Module <rootDir>/jest/setup.js in the setupFilesAfterEnv option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: /Users/alain/dev/ddf/release

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html

  error Command failed with exit code 1.
  ```
- my filesystem, in /Users/alain/dev/ddf/release/ i have

  ```
    babel.config.js
    jest.config.js
    /jest
      /setup
      setup.js ( so  full path is : /Users/alain/dev/ddf/release/jest/setup.js ) 
      staticFileAssetTransform.js ( so full path is : /Users/alain/dev/ddf/release/jest/staticFileAssetTransform.js )
  ```
- My package.json

  ```
  { ...
   "scripts": {
        "test": "jest __testsv2__ --config=./jest.config.js"
        ...
    }
  }
  ```
- babel.config.js

  ```
  module.exports = function(api) {
     api.cache(false);
     const presets = ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'];    
     const plugins = [['@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread'],];

     return {
       presets,    plugins,   sourceMaps: "inline",
       ignore: [(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test' ?  "**/*.test.js" : null)    ].filter(n => n)
     };
   };
  ```
- jest.config.js

  ```
   module.exports = {
    resolver: 'browser-resolve',
    clearMocks: true,
    moduleNameMapper: {    '\\.(css|less|styl|md)$': 'identity-obj-proxy'    },
    // A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test
    // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest/setup.js'], // don't work too
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest/setup.js'], 


    // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all test paths, matched tests are skipped
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/__gql_mocks__/'],

    // A map from regular expressions to paths to transformers
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.js$': './jest/babelRootModeUpwardTransform.js',
      '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': '<rootDir>/jest/staticFileAssetTransform.js',
    },
  };
  ```

Comment: try cat /Users/alain/dev/ddf/release/jest/setup.js to check if the file really exists

Answer (score 8):

For those coming here, make sure you prefix the path with `<rootDir>`

Like this:

`setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/@hirez_io/observer-spy/dist/setup-auto-unsubscribe.js']`

Comment: The `<rootDir>/` worked in a similar App in 2021 with Jest 26, and now won't work with Jest 29 on the same structure and config. Jest is not calling neither `setupFiles` nor `setupFilesAfterEnv`, while if you include them manually in test file, it works. Including it in all files is not very pretty.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to delete your *node modules*, package-lock.json and run `npm i` again, I had a similar issue and that was a fix for me. Also try `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I had `cd`ed into a test folder and run `ng test` and I thought I was going to have to revert a lot of work. But it appears I was in the wrong folder.

So `ng test` isn't expected to run anywhere but root of yoru project and if you do, you get an unintelligible error message.

Answer (score 2):

It's incorrect setup in the IDE (webstorm is in my case). Go to **Edit configuration** and then edit **working directory**

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: this worked for me, deleting until I was at the top level folder of the project (or wherever setupjest is for you) and it worked without changing any files. Nice !

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue too, after cracking my head around I discovered we can load the setup file using the command line arg itself. Run `jest --setupFilesAfterEnv=<rootDir>/jest/setup.js` and it will get discovered and loaded. Hope this helps.